# Are lumber prices now high enough that building with brick/concrete is more price efficient in the US?

Tags: brick, lumber, usa

I’m looking at purchasing a piece of land and building my own home within Washington state. Traditionally, single family homes around here are built with lumber rather than brick or concrete due to the costs involved.

But given the surging prices on lumber in the past year, is this really the case anymore? How can I estimate the end-to-end cost of each material given purchase, labor and long term maintenance costs?

Comment: You'll have to look at your local market for formed concrete, block (CMU) and/or brick and associated labor costs to make that call.

Comment: The cost of wood will not stay high... depends on how far out you are from actually starting construction. If lumber will be arriving on-site in the next few days/weeks, then *maybe*... but if you haven't even bought the land yet, then there's no way to predict what prices will be for wood by the time your builders are starting to frame out the foundation and subfloor.

Comment: Brick walls is heavier so you need to take in consideration the cost of base.

Comment: @TylerH sure but how do I make a fair estimate given whatever lumber/brick houses are in the future?

Comment: Given that you're in Washington State *anyway* you may be better off buying logs and milling them yourself.  The pinch point isn't logging. It's milling.  Logs are cheap.

Comment: I suspect the main reason that brick buildings are not built on the US west coast is the threat of earthquakes. This is certainly true in California. Obviously, reinforced concrete is used in many commercial buildings and would probably be fine for residential.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's hard to answer this objectively. Discuss with your lawyer when you think the purchase would be finalized and expect to be at the construction phase. If they don't know about construction timelines (likely), reach out to the general contractor(s) you are considering and ask them "given closing on X date, when would you expect to be at the lumber purchasing/construction phase with the foundation poured/built?". Then you can do some research on markets and current things affecting wood prices and make a personal estimate. Or just default back to what prices usually are.

Comment: But an estimate is just that: an estimate. If prices drop then your actual costs for materials will (should) drop. If they don't, it's because the GC uses a lumber supplier (or supplies it themselves from their own mill) where they price their lumber loads out at what they cost at the time of acquisition, and you should ask about that ahead of time so you aren't hit with sticker shock over that cost (though if you're not in construction, you're probably always going to have sticker shock when looking at lumber costs of a new house).

Answer (score 2):

You'd never go with brick in seismic zones.  Concrete and rebar construction is way more expensive than wood.  Even if wood is up 200% concrete is 10x more than wood.  Cost is not the biggest factor.  Wood is easier to work with, requires less skilled labor, can be reconfigured later, and is a better insulator than brick/steel.  Material cost is a factor but not "the" factor.

I have heard people are switching to steel studs.  You might want to look at SIPs ( structurally insulated panels ) that have wood members 4' oc and use ~1/3 of the wood - still probably not going to be cheaper but will perform better.  Really unless your labor is free - people won't have had the time / experience to effectively make using a different material more cost effective ( except possibly steel studs ).

Really how you cost compare depends a lot on how you are going to have your house built.  If you are acting as the general then you'd get bids from people based on your plans.  If you want to compare cost in wood vs cost in steel, again it will depend on who you are getting to do the work.  Some subs will include material others will have the general order the material and the subs just do the labor.  In some cases you have a structural engineer who could do the plans with steel or wood.  The lumber yards then sometimes have their structural then do plans and take offs.  Steel I imagine would be similar.

Given the lower availability of people who work with anything but lumber I can't see a cost savings.

Comment: Are you using conventional cast-in-place concrete or IC(C)F as your baseline for concrete construction?

Comment: Cast in place.  ICF the walls are typically thinner so you'd use less concrete and you'd have better insulation value but still quite expensive for the ICF framework.   Even commercial construction for mid to high rise you don't see them using interior concrete walls - they go to steel stud.